# Base table or view not found laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I upload my project on the server , and if i run 'php artisan migrate' i got : "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_lara .tags2' doesn't exist"

I created this table manually with phpmyadmin and I runned again 'php artisan migrate' i got 'Base table or view already exist'

Whats wrong guys, I am confused here

Thanks

Comment: Please show your migration(s) which you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed this new table 'db_lara .tags2' manually first and then you can do migration of it.